# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
         \frac{\ln{(1+x^2 y^2})}{x} & , & x \neq0 \\
         0 & , & x=0
         \end{cases}$$

My idea is to prove that all partial derivatives are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y^2-\ln{(1+x^2y^2)(1+x^2y^2)}}{(1+x^2y^2)x^2} \qquad , \quad x\neq 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac1{x}\frac1{1+x^2y^2}2yx^2 \qquad , \quad x \neq 0$$

Now I want to find partial derivatives for $x=0$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,y)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln{(1+h^2y^2)}}{h^2}$$

I don't know how to compute this limit. Am I doing something wrong? After that I would prove that partial derivatives are continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about it, but is the concept good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the final limit (assuming earlier calculations are correct) you can use de L'Hopital
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln{(1+h^2y^2)}}{h^2}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2hy^2}{2h(1+h^2y^2)}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y^2}{1+h^2y^2}=y^2
$$
On the other hand:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y^2-\ln{(1+x^2y^2)(1+x^2y^2)}}{(1+x^2y^2)x^2} = \frac{2y^2}{1+x^2y^2} - \frac{\ln{(1+x^2y^2)}}{x^2}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = 2y^2-y^2=y^2=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)
$$

Comment: Thank you, do I have to check partial derivative for $y$ at $0$? I think yes

Comment: Yes you need to do that at $(0,y)$ but it will be a much easier calculation.

Comment: I get $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0,y+h)}{h}=\frac{0}{0}$$

Comment: @RushThaMan You will need to use L'Hopital then